# "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Uint' "

Tags: swift

```
let expdate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("expiration") as! NSDate
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: expdate)
            var theyear =  components.year
            var themonth = components.month

            stripCard.expMonth = themonth
            stripCard.expYear = theyear
```

On the last 2 lines I'm getting an error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type "Uint'. I've tried casting and it still won't work

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you tried casting, I assume you mean something like:

```
stripCard.expMonth = themonth as! UInt
```

But casting won't work because they are completely different types.  Instead, try converting using UInt's initializer that takes an Int, like this:

```
stripCard.expMonth = UInt(themonth)
```